# How to use TS generics to extract correct type from state when reducing

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given a state reducer like this:

```js
const anObject = {
  fruit: 'Apple',
  today: new Date(),
}

function reducer(state, stateReducer) {
  return stateReducer(state);
}

const fruit = reducer(anObject, state => state.fruit);
// fruit should be of type string.

const now = reducer(anObject, state => state.now);
// now should be of type Date.
```

I would like use Typescript generics so that the returned state from `reducer(anObject, state => state.someState)` is the correct type according to the part of the start it returns. How can I achieve that? Thanks

Here's a runnable example of the above: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-booth-jlnhn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the return type of the `reducer` function should be just the same as the return type of the passed `stateGetter` function. Additionally, `stateGetter` should accept as its arugment the same type passed as the first argument to `reducer`.

So if `S` is the type of the state, and `R` is the return type of `stateGetter`, then you could write the function like so:

```
function reducer<S, R>(state: S, stateGetter: (state: S) => R): R { /* ... */ }
```

Then the inferences you want happen:

```
const fruit = reducer(anObject, state => state.fruit); // Has type: string
const today = reducer(anObject, state => state.today); // Has type: Date
```

[Here's your codesandbox with that modification.](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-tree-7yrpp)